# Bash Partial Unzip of Archive in Loop

Tags: bash, unzip

I have a series of zip archives from which I wish to extract one text file to an output directory. the file is in the general location:

`archive.zip/archive/summary.txt`

I have the following code that I thought should work:

```
for file in *.zip
do
   name=${file##*/}
   base=${name%.zip}
   unzip -j $name/$base/summary.txt -d /$output/$file-summary.txt
done
```

However unzip cannot find the text files.

Comment: **1.** What's the value "$output" ? **2.** I would run a check with `sed -x` ( or `bash -x yourscript` to output the exact command that will run after parsing and expanding. **3.** "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and _every_ expansion: "$var", "$(command "$var")", "${array[@]}", "a & b". See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words .

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein: I think I was getting the output and extract directories a little wrong in the unzip command and I also added the double quotes. I will add the code I got to work below as an answer. It may someday be useful for somebody.

Comment: Great. I'll even give you a vote up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the following did what I wanted:

```
for file in *.zip
do
   name=${file##*/}
   base=${name%.zip}
   unzip -j "$name" "$base/summary.txt" -d "$output/$base"
done
```